# cannot pass a variable with onclick after getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, zepto

In my database I have a row with article name and article link.  I'm retrieving the information like this:

```
<div id="daily"></div>

$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getmainnews.php', function(data){
  daily = data.items;
  $.each(daily, function(index, news){
    $('#daily').append('<a href="#" onclick="displaylink('+ news.link +');">' + news.article + '</a>');
  });
});
function displaylink(link){
  alert(link);
}
```

So all I want to do is get the link and pass it with onclick.  I'm using Zepto.js.  The news.article is displaying correctly but when I click on the link, I get this error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :   main.html:1"

If my onclick parameters are empty, the onclick works.  Is it a problem with the link?  Does it not like the colon in the link?  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
onclick="displaylink('+ news.link +');" to onclick="displaylink(\''+ news.link +'\');"
```

Comment: That worked...I tried so many combinations, just not that one I guess.  Thanks!